Starting a Swift App: Unable to do "init pod"
I am trying to write my first SwiftUI mobile app. I have created an XCode project already and now I am trying to create a Podfile that will hold all my external Pod libraries. I try to run pod init but then I recieve this error:
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

/usr/local/bin/pod init

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin24]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 15.0 (24A5327a)
       Xcode :  ()
         Git : git version 2.36.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

### Error

RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup` from attributes: `{"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", "exceptions"=>["7718906C2C7CAFDA003960FF"], "explicitFileTypes"=>{}, "explicitFolders"=>[], "path"=>"chuber", "sourceTree"=>"<group>"}`
If this ISA was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:359:in `rescue in object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:349:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:290:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:213:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

I have tried to do init pod which needs to create a Podfile that will hold all my external Pod libraries in my Swift project. What can I do to solve this?

"xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance" That's the main error, look for it.

Not answering the question but I would recommend avoiding pods if it's possible and use SPM instead
